What is the fourier transform of$ -\frac{4Bax}{(a^2+x^2)^2} $?
I though of using the known results for $ -4Bax$ ,  $\frac{1}{a^2+x^2}$ and $\frac{1}{a^2+x^2}$ by doing Convolution yet i have not seen it used before for 3 functions , my knowledge does not include complex analysis so I would appreciate some  basic  techniques to simplify the problem . $B$ and $a$ are constants, the fourier transform is from $x$ to $k$ such that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)e^{-ixk}dx$.

What are the limits? $-\pi$ to $\pi$??

from -inf to inf and the fourier transform includes scaling by$ \frac{1}{sqrt{2\pi}}$

i have wrote the function incorrectly though so i will make an edit to the post

I've computed it here (you first need to do a substitution)

@SineoftheTime Isn't that slightly different since it doesn't have $x$ in the numerator?

@QuantumWiz Note that, at a certain point, I've computed $\mathcal F[-2xf]$ where $f(x)=(x^2+1)^{-2}$

Hint:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{a^2+x^2}=\frac{-2x}{(a^2+x^2)^2}$$
Is this enough for you?

i did not consider  that i may know the transform of the integral of the function i will try

@lodo Did you figure it out?

i calculated and reached an expression, i am not sure if the expression is correct  but certainly it is a problem on my part ,you answered what i should be doing i will accept the answer (i forgot to thank you)

Maybe you can e.g. check if this answer by Wolfram Alpha is the same as yours. https://tinyurl.com/2us5kaz4
